# Dropdown Selected IndexChanged is not firing

Tags: asp.net

I have one dropdownlist and its autopostback property is set to true.But when value is changed  the selectedindexchanged property is not fired instead it is always going to pageload.Please tell what is the issue.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlVendor" CssClass="ddl" runat="server"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlVendor_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">


protected void ddlVendor_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<ProcurementItem> vendorsList = new List<ProcurementItem>();
    vendorsList = (List<ProcurementItem>)ViewState["VendorList"];
    string ID = string.Empty;
    string accountID = string.Empty;
    int? accountType = null;
    if (ddlVendor.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        ID = ddlVendor.SelectedValue;


        ProcurementClient procurementClient = new ProcurementClient();

        List<ProcurementContract> contractList =    
       procurementClient.GetContractList(Convert.ToInt32(ID), null);
        contractList = contractList.Where(i => i.Status == 4).ToList();
        ddlContracts.DataSource = contractList;
        ddlContracts.DataTextField = "ContractIDName";
        ddlContracts.DataValueField = "ContractID";
        ddlContracts.DataBind();
        ddlContracts.Items.Insert(0, "");
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please show your code?

Comment: Is this control  in updatepanel? If yes set EnableViewState=true and check.

Comment: `Page_Load` will always be hit with a postback, can you post your **code-behind** by editing the question

Comment: then there has to be some validation error! assign a unique ValidationGroup to your ddl, and see if it starts postBack, if it does, somewhere validators where getting raised, check them out

Comment: Set EnableViewState="true" in page directive and form

Comment: so, if you set a break here `ddlVendor_SelectedIndexChanged`, it doesn't get hit?

Comment: No Sir, nothing is working for me

Comment: use causevalidation= false with the dropdown and check if it is coming to it ?

Comment: AutoEventWireup="true" check this also on the page directives

Comment: But still it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following **property** in  **DropDownList**

1.**ViewStateMode="Enabled"**

2.**EnableViewState="true"**

3.**AutoPostBack="true"**

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<asp:dropdownlist id=ddltrim width="100%" Runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" EnableViewState="True" onselectedindexchanged="ddltrim_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

Make Sure That your DropDownList within the Fom tag

```
<form>

//

</form>
```

Comment: Dropdownlist is inside asp.net page

Answer (score 0):

dear check the causesvalidation= false

may be this is the problem
if you have any validations in your page dear

Thanks

:D

Answer (score 0):

If you are filling the dropdown list from database then, make sure that the DataBind() method of dropdown list is called only when its not a post back as...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
...
       If(!Page.IsPostBack)
       {
             ......
             dropdownlist.DataBind();
             .....
       }
...
}
```

Hope this helps :)